# rotate image to a certain angle in angular 4

Tags: javascript, image, angular, rotation, angular2-template

Guys,I have an image file already selected in typescript . How can i rotate the image file before uploading it to server. I have  already got the orientation of the image and accordingly I want the image file to rotate a certain angle.I have got the angle also by which it should rotate. The only thing i can't figure out is how to rotate the image file. I guess .rotate function is deprecated in angular 4.

Here is my function which detects my image file before uploading it to server.

```
'detectFiles(event) {
this.getOrientation(event.target.files[0], function(orientation) {
  this.imageOrientation = orientation;
  this.finAngle = this.finalAngle(this.imageOrientation);
}.bind(this));
 this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
 this.fileConditions(this.selectedFiles); }'
```

'SelectedFiles' holds the selected image file which should be rotated before uploading.

'finalAngle' function decides the angle by which selected file  should be rotated .

How can i rotate my selected file now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think this is only achievable on the backend part of your app. You are changing the orientation of the rendering of the image on the browser, not of the file, per se. Do you have access to this app's API?

Comment: did you try ` canvas rotate()`

Comment: @BrunoPoeta I guess we can acheive this on front end . I am not able to rotate the image using the 'rotate()' function in angular4.

Comment: @RahulSingh yeah i tried canvas rotate ,it ain't working.

Comment: @Shabih Check this right here: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image